# Dimensional regularization order of integration

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-regularization

I simply have a question of which integration I should perform first. Consider the typical integral from some loop calculation that has had the Feynman-trick and the typical dim-reg procedure perform,
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d}\int_0^1dx\frac{1}{(p^2 - \Delta)^2}.
\end{equation}

Should I perform the momentum integration first or the $x$ integral first? Does the answer change if I have factors of $p^2$, $p^4$ multiplied by some factors of the metric (which for integration don't matter) in the numerator? By pure intuition I would think it matters and I should perform the momentum integral first, but I can't pin down why. This is because I know the $\Delta$ has a factor of $x$ *but* no $p$ (for clarity it is actually $\Delta = q^2(1-x) + m^2$).

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Is this in Euclidean or Minkowskian signature?

Comment: In Minkowskian signature there should be an $i\epsilon$ somewhere in the denominator.

Comment: @Qmechanic well could you give both cases, whether or not it is Minkowski or Eculidean?

Comment: Evaluating the $x$ integral first would just be undoing the Feynman trick.

Comment: In Euclidean signature, the integrand is non-negative, and Tonelli's theorem shows that that one may change the order of integration.

Comment: @Qmechanic ok, but in Minkowski I couldn't then, also the denominator would now be $\Delta = q^2(1-x) + m^2 + i\epsilon$, and this $\epsilon$ is the same as in dim-reg? Also, if I had any $p^\mu$ momentum in the numerator I would need to keep all the $i\epsilon$ terms in there as well correct? I could just truncate off to order $\epsilon$ right?

Comment: The $i\epsilon$ prescription is independent of dim-reg.

Comment: @Qmechanic Oh wait, the $i\epsilon$ would never been seen in the numerator since it is not part of me completing the square... I need more coffee. Thanks! So I am working in the Minkowski signature and will complete the momentum integral first then the $dx$ integral since I don't want to keep track of negatives and just want to use the integral formulas in the back of P&S. Thanks again.